# I can't connect with Chatango via Java

Tags: java

If anyone knows why I can't connect with chatango using this code? It's weird, I'm sure that server and port are correct. Nothing appears in room deinos.chatango.com

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException{
     //The Server
        String server = "s14.chatango.com";
        String str = "Hi,I am connecting to chatango using java :)\r\n\0";
        int port = 443;
     //The Socket Connection
     Socket sock = new Socket( server, port );

    InetAddress addr = sock.getInetAddress();
    //Print Connected
    System.out.println("Connected to " + addr);



    PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in =  new BufferedReader(new           InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    //Send Authorization to deinos
    out.println("bauth:deinos\0");
    //Print the String      
    out.println(str);

    //Closing all Connections        
        out.flush();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        sock.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: it's because the code ain't following the new chatango protocol, see my other answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39055438/1986995